# How to compare current password with new password mac - dscl

Tags: mac, passwords, bash-scripting

I am writing a script to change the admin password on all of our macs.

Its a =basic script, but I would like to check if the password is already correct before attempting to change it:

```
if [ currentPwd == newPwd ] then

echo 'password is correct'
else

#change account password

fi
```

This is the line I'm using to change the password:

```
#Change management account locally on mac
sudo dscl . passwd /Users/"${accountName}" "${currentPassword}" "${newPassword}"

echo " Local Admin Account - Password changed! "
```

This works fine, but I want to first check that the password hasn't already been changed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, with the quotes: note single `=`

```sh
if [ "$currentPassword" = "$newPassword" ]; then
    echo already changed
else
    sudo dscl ...
    echo Password changed
fi
```

Comment: I don't know how to get $currentPassword. I will pass in $newPassword but how do I get the currently set password? Do I use dscl -read?

Comment: You say "This works fine", so don't you have it already?

Comment: I would be VERY concerned if you could just ask my computer for my password.

Comment: Because this script is going to be run every day, I don't want to run the script on a machine if the password has already been changed. Thats what I'm trying to figure out. I don't need to know what the currentPwd is I just need to know if it matches the newPwd or not

Comment: You must know what the old password is, before you can elevate permission to change it. Mainly I'm wondering why someone is enforcing password changes in this day & age, when it has long been proven to be less secure than enforcing a good password policy in the first place. Users make patterns &/or write them down.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem :

```
#Check for authentication 
        sudo dscl /Local/Default -authonly "${accountName}" "${currentPassword}" 2>&1 /dev/null
        if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
            #Exit code was not 0 - password has already been changed so no further action
            echo "No action taken, account already updated! "
```